# RecyclerView Adapter OnClick not Called

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have list of items coming from server and I am trying to inflate it in `RecyclerView`. However, on clicking those items, nothing is happening, even if I have implemented the `View.onClickListener` in `MyViewHolder` class.

Here's my code for the adapter.

```
class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<User> list;
    Context context;
    UserAdapter(ArrayList<User>list,Context context) {
        Log.e("Listsizeis","" +list.size());
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.e("InsideOnCreate","Yes");
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView,context,list,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("InsideOnBind","Yes");
        User u = list.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(u.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(list.size() ==0) return 1;
        else return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        private UserAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<User> userArrayList;
        Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View view,Context context,ArrayList<User> userArrayList,UserAdapter adapter) {
            super(view);
            Log.e("OnMyviewHolder","yes" + userArrayList.size());
            this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
            this.context = context;
            title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("OnMyviewHolderItem","yes" + userArrayList.size());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

`onClick` function is not invoking on clicking the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really do not understand what's the point of passing the adapter itself into your `ViewHolder`. Anyway, I would like to suggest the following changes in your `ViewHolder` which should work.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   public TextView title;
   ArrayList<User> userArrayList;
   Context context;

   public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
        super(view);
        Log.e("OnMyviewHolder","yes" + userArrayList.size());
        this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

    public void bindView(final int pos) {
        title.setText(userArrayList.get(pos).getName());
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, userArrayList.get(pos) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in your `BindViewHolder` function, you need to call the `bindView` function once you have initialized the `ViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) holder;
    vh.bindView(position);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Reaz Murshed It worked but just wanted to it wasn't working on the firsttime?

Comment: Where should i set this setOnclickListener with my views?

Comment: I have updated the previous comment already. You should have set it inside the constructor of your `ViewHolder`.